# Is it okay to read text files as binary?

Tags: c, fopen

I am working on GLSL shader program loader. The shader programs are just plain texts with source code inside. I can open them by calling `fopen()` in binary mode, it is much easy. But as my source files are texts, should I proper use `fopen()` as for working with text files called without binary flag and read them line by line? Which is more tedious to concatenate whole text line by line, and line buffer lengths getting capped being read by `fgets()`. So if there any line longer than buffer, the read would be failed. But programs… They are text files by the way… What the disadvantages of reading text files in binary mode? May be encoding or line ending issues will come up? What should I do? Should I read them in binary mode, or text mode though?

Comment: What are you doing with the contents of the files once you have read from them? Are you just passing the contents on to so GLSL function? If yes, can you be specific about the function you are passing the contents to?

Comment: @ShaneBishop yes I am. Just passing buffer contents to `glShaderSource()` and then calling `glCompileShader()`, so far nothing complicated.

Comment: Does GLSL support Unicode or any other multi-byte character encoding? If not, then it shouldn't matter if you read the file as text or as binary, as the binary representation of the text will be the same. Also as pointed out by @datenwolf, you don't need to do any string concatenation, since `glShaderSource()` accepts an array of strings.

Comment: Looking at [the GLSL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf), I see that it supports Unicode.

Comment: Again, looking at the GLSL spec, it looks like the language requires a semicolon at the end of each statement. This means the language does not require whitespace to separate statements, and therefore it does not matter what line endings the input file has.

Comment: @ShaneBishop True about line endings, yet many text files of today employ a leading byte-order mark bytes and of yore a possible tailing Ctrl Z.  Text vs binary is more than just line endings.

Comment: @Alex Anything more needed on this post?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica nah, I saw this question gained a lot of views and I seen your answer and really like it. I agree with that text processing is not only about handling line endings, but there might be such other data like encoding byte marks, so in most cases it better to standard library or OS API to handle that.

Answer (score 4):

**A disadvantage of reading text files in text mode.**

- Cross-platform usage.

Text files in their native platform work well being opened in *text* mode.  Yet working with across platforms can readily break file processing should a `"\n"` file get read in a `"\r\n"` system - and visa versa.

To well handle just this text file variation requires us to test at *least* 4 conditions:

- `"\n"` file gets read in a `"\n"` system.
- `"\n"` file gets read in a `"\r\n"` system.
- `"\r\n"` file gets read in a `"\n"` system.
- `"\r\n"` file gets read in a `"\r\n"` system.

If the file was read as binary, we worry about half the number of cases, 2,  Thus a testing advantage.

- `"\n"` file.
- `"\r\n"` file.

We could read a *line* in the above 2 cases with `fgets()` and then lop off the potential end-of-line with common code:

```
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n\r")] = '\0';
```

**Yet is that enough?**

This is not truly as some older systems have been know to use `'\r'` as the end-of-line. In that case, the above code is insufficient as `fgets()` will not find a `'\n'`.

The above code also assumes `'\r'` does not appears except at the line end.

**Other considerations**

- The leads bytes may be a [byte-order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
- The last byte may be a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and is is not really part of the text.
- End-of-lines may be a mixture of `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, `"\r"`, or others due to mixed history editors that assumed a certain ending.
- The last line may/may not end with a proper end-of-line character.
- Narrow vs. wide characters.
- Future: By opening in text mode, we count on the current system to handle current text file formats, not just the ones we knew about at the time of writing code.

---

**Bottom line**

- Use text mode unless cross-platform usage is possible.
- Otherwise use binary mode on *text* files and [be prepared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_Motto) to handle *many* text file standards.  (IMO: this means reading at least a portion of the file as binary, analyzing what type of text file it is and then proceeding with crafted text handing or re-opening in text mode as a fall-back case.)

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file in text mode if you're going to process it as lines. Text mode automatically converts the operating system's line break character to `\n`. So on Windows, the `\r\n` sequence will be translated to `\n`, and `fgets()` will use `\r\n` as the line delimiter; on Unix the newline character is already `\n`, so no translation is needed, and there's no difference between binary and text mode.

Comment: "So on Windows, the \r\n sequence will be translated to \n, and fgets() will use \r\n as the line delimiter" --> It is more of a compiler/library choice than OS.  Example: My gcc on windows looks for a `'\n'`.  A `"\r\n"` sequence is _not_ translated to `"\n"`.

Comment: The standard says this is implementation-dependent, so anything is allowed. But it seems more appropriate for a Windows library to implement Windows conventions. I'm not sure why GCC would deliberately violate this expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The `binary` / `text` flags to `fopen` are just about newline conversions. `binary` just passes through newlines as is, `text` will convert newline sequences common to the OS the program is running on, to simple `\n` single byte newlines. The GLSL compiler doesn't care at all about what kind of newline (Unix style `\n`, Windows/DOS style `\r\n`, RISC OS style `\n\r`) it sees, it's all whitespace to it, anyhow.

Also there's no need to present OpenGL with split lines. That `glShaderSource` takes an array of strings is meant as a convenience, so that you can have some common shader strings, that you put as a header or similar into the source string vector. But just supplying a single long string is perfectly fine.

Comment: "The binary / text flags to fopen are just about newline conversions." -- This statement is not correct. On Microsoft Windows, in text mode, the character code `0x1A` also has the meaning of an end-of-file character. Therefore, opening a binary file in text mode will often make the file appear shorter than it actually is.

Comment: Well, I got it in case of GLSL loading. I tried to ask question in such a way to cover all cases where it controversial how to read text files.
I am using your linmath library for trigonometry and even commited a minor change back then, it such a surprise to get a specified answer to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: MSDN reference of `fopen` says *"__b__ – Open in binary (untranslated) mode; translations involving carriage-return and line feed characters are suppressed."* and then *"n text mode, CTRL+Z is interpreted as an EOF character on input."*, so the EOF translation is with regard from interactive input from a terminal (sort of like the difference between raw and canonical tty/pts mode on POSIX)

Answer (score 0):

I am presented with "what is appropriate for the expert is not appropriate for the novice." If you want to proceed, here is your path:

- Get told No
- Try to do it
- Learn why not
- Adapt
- Learn
- Develop the library that is a mirror image of the input libraries
- Discover the No has become yes.

Or are just copying files? If so, no problem. Open and copy away.

In the old days we had this thing about text files; you got your platform's behavior on opening them and when copying files between systems you had to convert line endings.

Those days are passing away; everybody is abandoning `fopen` in text mode and just accepting any line endings using a simple state machine.

Comment: `dos2unix` & `unix2dos`

Comment: @SparKot but it is external utilities? Should I process text files each time before load them into application?

Comment: @Alex I was commenting on `Old days` & `Those days`, wondering he meant those.

Comment: The last paragraph explains what I doubted. It seems that reading text files by standard library was pretty useful at one time, few were worried about line length overrun in favor of perfomance, because reading string in fixed char array is stupidly fast! There no allocations/reallocations on heap. As I seen it in released golden source engine source code. But it has lost its relevance as computers have become more powerful and there come much room in performance for dynamic length strings implementations to be used ubiquitously. I'm right?

Comment: @SparKot: Every single text editor I've used recently has line ending sense now.